# JPA @OneToMany with @EmbeddedId

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following Class (Parent):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROBE_CUSTOMERS")
public class ProbeCustomer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String hostname;
    private List<ProbeMonitor> monitors;

    ....
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "Probe_Monitors", 
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "Df_Customer")})
    @XmlElement(name = "monitors")
    @JsonProperty
    public List<ProbeMonitor> getMonitors() {
        return monitors;
    }
}
```

The list (of type `ProbeMonitor`) have an `@EmbeddedId` defined as this:

```
@Embeddable
public class ProbeMonitorId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String customer;
    private String name;
    private String type;
}
```

The Child class define a primary key as the embedded id:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROBE_MONITORS")
public class ProbeMonitor implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private ProbeMonitorId id;
    private Integer active;

    @EmbeddedId
    @XmlElement
    @JsonProperty
    public ProbeMonitorId getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

When i create an entity of `ProbeCustomer` and i try to call the save method (using `CrudRepository`)
I get the following (wrong insert statement) - in the insert there are more field than i have wrote there, i've removed for brevity:

```
insert into PROBE_CUSTOMERS (Df_Hostname, Dt_Insert, Df_Customer, Dt_Update, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
insert into PROBE_MONITORS (Fl_Active, Dt_Insert, Dt_Update, Df_Customer, Df_Monitor, Df_Type) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
insert into Probe_Monitors (Df_Customer, monitors_Df_Customer, monitors_Df_Monitor, monitors_Df_Type) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Where i wrong defining the relationship ?

Comment: Somehow the fields in your inserts and the fields in the mapping do not match. It's hard to find which ones are wrong when all of them are unexpected.

Comment: Looking on the net i've found an article and i've semplified the @OneToMany like this @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.customer", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY). And with this all works